# Custom template - How to find out whether a user has permission to access a content?

Tags: 7, users

The case is as following:

- User A has access to content X and Y
- User A adds a reference field to link from content X to content Y
- User A is able to access content X and see the link to content Y and also is allowed to click on it to get forwareded to content Y
- User B is just allowed to access content X but NOT content Y
- User B should be able to see that there is a link to content Y but not be able to click on it!

The last list item is what I want to do. When I use `print_r(get_defined_vars());` for User A and B I do get different outputs but cannot really see the needed difference. In some lines of my output the link to content Y is just shown in a different line or the structure ist just a bit different. To give an example:
User A's output:

```
[field_referenced_strategy] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [target_id] => 69
                        [entity] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [vid] => 69
                                [uid] => 1
                                [title] => Strategy abc
                                [log] => 
                                [status] => 1
                                [comment] => 2
                                [promote] => 1
                                [sticky] => 0
                                [nid] => 69
                                [type] => ct_strategy
                                [language] => en
                                [created] => 1439297478
                                [changed] => 1441705417
                                [tnid] => 0
                                [translate] => 0
                                [revision_timestamp] => 1441705417
                                [revision_uid] => 1
                                [body] => Array
```

User B's output:

```
[field_referenced_strategy] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [target_id] => 69
                                [entity] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [vid] => 69
                                        [uid] => 1
                                        [title] => Strategy abc
                                        [log] => 
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [comment] => 2
                                        [promote] => 1
                                        [sticky] => 0
                                        [nid] => 69
                                        [type] => ct_strategy
                                        [language] => en
                                        [created] => 1439297478
                                        [changed] => 1441705417
                                        [tnid] => 0
                                        [translate] => 0
                                        [revision_timestamp] => 1441705417
                                        [revision_uid] => 1
                                        [body] => Array
```

This is just a part of my output. But as you can see the structure is even different but there is not flag or anything like that that distinguishs the accessibility of the user.

I hope my point is clear.

Comment: You should never, ever leave permission checking to *theming layer*. That's not where it belongs. If user shouldn't see something, it should never get visible for templating files. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I use organic groups to manage sub units. Sub units contain content as strategy, goals and so on. When I have a Sub Unit A that does contain a strategy A and is related to strategy B (belongs to unit B) I want to show the members that there is a related strategy. But if user A is only a member of unit B he won't be able to look at the strategy A. If user B is a member of unit A and B he will be able to look at both strategies. That's why I am trying to do that. Do you think there is another way to do so?

Comment: There should be - after all some cache systems assume that if theme gets one set of data, it will return the same HTML. In your case this may lead to security breach. Some things like show-hide link pose little risk as the linked page contains it's own checks, but you want to use it on actual data. It's a problem waiting to happen. If I was in your place, I'd try to research hooks to make it happen in module.

Comment: Actually, I am suprised that I can get all variables even though the user should not be able to access the node. I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [user_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) funtion

Comment: Please add some excerpt, a sentence or two about usage.